# If Match is in the beginning of the String then... in ."Regex" Conditional

Tags: .net, regex, conditional-statements

)) Hi all, I would like to create a regEx Conditional of this syntax (?(regex)then|else) please a regex.
This is my string...

```
cook, eat, write, play
```

currently Im using this Regex

```
(, )?write
```

... and replace it with "" (nothing, just delete it)

in order to delete the "write word" and the "comma and space" thay may or may not appear before it. So after applied I get this string...

```
cook, eat, play
```

But If I would like to delete the first word "cook" in the string using the same Regex `(, )?cook`, I would get this awkward result...

```
, eat, write, play
```

So, I would like to create a Regex conditional that could check...
If a Match is found at the beginning of the string then delete the same that before but also the following "comma and space" so it gives the result...

```
eat, write, play
```

How can I create that conditional? or is any other better Regex to do that??
Please notice that Im using a Macro Automation tool that only allow me to Replace Text using Regex, Im not programming in any language that could replace the Regex. Please I need only a Regex solution, Im using this only .NET Regex tester. http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Thanks Advanced.

Comment: I did not understand your requirement. But if you want to match from the beginning then add `^`. Say for example `^\w+@\w+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}` for email

Comment: String.Spilt(), Remove whatever element you want to remove from the array, String.Join() the remaining elements.

Comment: Why not just use YourString.split(" "c)?

Comment: Going off of @Shar1er80: `string.Join(str.Split(", ").Where(s => s != "write"), ", ")`

Comment: Hi @Vinod Kumar, yes I know ^ means start and $ means end of the string, I need to create a Conditional, (?(regex)then|else) syntax, do you know how to create a conditional in Regex?

Comment: Hi, @Shar1er80, I am not programming in .NET, I am using a Macro automation tool that can execute "Replace Text" using Regex (.NET flavor of Regex to be more specific). Please I need a the Regex syntax for a conditional. Thanks Advanced. please look at my example, how could I achive this taks using only Regex? Thanks Advanced. PD: Macro automation tool that Im using doesn't have any string.split like feature. Ive already search for that.THanks Again.

Comment: Hi @Feign, please read my answer above

Comment: Hi  @Jashaszun please read my answer above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish it were more complicated but if you have to have a conditional,
its (expressional): `@"(?(^)write,[ ]|,[ ]write)"`

```
 (?( ^ )              # Conditional, is at BOS ? 
      write, [ ]          # Yes, this form
   |                     # else
      , [ ] write          # No, this form
 )                    # end conditional.
```

but, the same is achieved without a conditional: `@"^write,[ ]|,[ ]write"`

```
   ^ write , [ ]
|  
   , [ ] write
```

But, it could be more sophisticated using a conditional. `@"(?>(^)?)(?:,[ ])?write(?(1),[ ])"`

```
 (?>( ^ )?)           # (1), Optional BOS, with atomic group
 (?: , [ ] )?         # Optional comma space for all 
 write                # 'write'
 (?(1) , [ ] )        # Conditional, if group 1 matched, 
                      # then match the space comma after
                      # otherwise, don't match anything else.
```

Comment: It doesn't work, to me, is that a Regex? man could you please test it in this only regex tester of .Net flavor? please I need a Regex of .Net flavor http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: What does "$" mean in your code? $ in regex means end of the line. What does BOS mean in your comments??? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'll fix it. Ok, changed to `^` ,,

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, to me. Are you using replace with??? or just Match. Please test in this page http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx is a .NET flavor Regex

Comment: please use my example, My string is `cook, eat, write, play` I would like to get the result `eat, write, play` What regex should I use??? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: only the first two regex work, but not if Im looking for the word "cook" in my example.

Comment: Please take a look to my question, I edited it in order to better explain it. Thanks Advanced.

Comment: If you expect to do this globally over several lines, be sure to set the multi-line regex option.

Comment: In fact, is espected to be used in a single line. btw why you put @" before you regex? is it any programming language convention???

Comment: `Please take a look to my question, I edited it in order to better explain it` - The question is fully answered now. If you have another question, open up a new one, or modify this one. As of now, this is the answer. If you feel it doesn't work, show an input that doesn't work for you.

Comment: _show an input taht doesn't work for you_ ??? I have enable multine by doint `(?m)` How do I enable global??

Comment: The regex is _Dot-Net_, the `@""` notation is a C# string literal. If you want to use it in vb.net or some other incarnation, simply remove that notation.

Comment: `How do I enable global` - Global does not have an inline modifier designation, see the docs for the replacement function, you will use. It's usually of the `replaceAll()` form, or `replace(,,"global")`.

Comment: Yes of corse Im doing that, I guess is Im not enabling global, Ill keep testing it out, thanks

Comment: Thanks@sln I got the last one to work, in the online regextester, but in my ReggexBuddy still doesn't work, it highlightme the `(?(1),[ ])` part of your last regex, it is calling the group that you created by doing `(?: , [ ] )?` right? the `?:` records the group am I right? My regex buddy is using .Net 4.5.

Comment: It means _RegexBuddy_ doesn't/can't test capture group conditionals. All engines that support conditionals, support capture group number ones. Some engines might support it as `(?(<1>))` but usually is not the case. Some support different conditionals, like Dot-Net supports _expressional_, where as Perl does not. Check with Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks @sln very illustrative, Many thanks, I have one huge doubt though, In a lot of regex I made before I always refer to space like this `( )` I know I should to avoid using `\s` to refer to space, cuz it includes carriage return, line feed, etc, But why you refer to space using `[ ]` why? I have try to replace the `[ ]` with `( )` in your code, but doing so, it disables your code, why is that. Thanks Again man!

Comment: No problem. Square brackets are a _character class_.  `[ ]` has a single space in it. Its a way of saying a single space that works, and is easily readable in both ignore whitespace, or non-ignore whitespace mode, without having to do anything else. This is mostly for illustrative purpose.

Comment: Hi @slnI Thanks, I actually made it into another question, please if you can, check it out, hope you can give me a hand with that stackoverflow.com/questions/31257590/… ThanksAdvanced

Comment: @litu16 - Added the atomic group. I answered it over there, but _that_ question's answere should be applied here, and not there.