# How regex groups behaves inside conditional?

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, regex-lookarounds

I'm having a hard time with regex conditionals (.net regex).

suppose this is my string `eat, drink, run`

I'm wondering if this regex

```
(eat)
```

stores "eat" in the group 1, being enclosed by parenthesis, and this

```
(?:eat)
```

doesn't store the match in any group, because there is a "?:" inside the parenthesis

Then, why this conditional regex doesn't work?

```
(eat)(?(1)a)
```

displaying a message saying that nothing is stored in group 1, isn't (eat) properly stored as a group?

And why this conditional regex does work?

```
(^)?eat(?(1)a)
```

returning that "eat" is stored in group 1, isn't supposed that matches meant to be stored in groups must be enclosed with parenthesis?

Please I have try to find an explanation in many sites, I'm testing these regex in this .NET regex page http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the concept of [conditionals in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html).

> A special construct `(?ifthen|else)` allows you to create conditional regular expressions. If the *if* part evaluates to true, then the regex engine will attempt to match the then part. Otherwise, the *else* part is attempted instead. 
>   ... **you can check in the *if* part whether a capturing group has taken part in the match thus far**. Place the number of the capturing group inside parentheses, and use that as the if part.

And from [MSDN Details of Regular Expression Behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e347654k(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Conditional evaluation: `(?(expression)yes|no)` and `(?(name)yes|no)`, where `expression` is a subexpression to match, `name` is the name of a capturing group, `yes` is the string to match **if `expression` is matched or `name` is a valid, non-empty captured group**, and `no` is the subexpression to match if `expression` is not matched or `name` is not a valid, non-empty captured group.

With that information in mind, it is easy to explain your pattern behavior.

> why this conditional regex doesn't work?

`(eat)(?(1)a)` won't work because the regex engine found `eat`, placed it into the capturing group (into stack #1) and encountered a conditional statement. It checks if Group 1 participated in a match (due to `(?(1)...)`). Yes, it did. The engine then looks for the `if` part in the conditional (`a`) right after `eat`. There is no `a`, thus, **the whole match fails**.

> And why this conditional regex does work?

In `(^)?eat(?(1)a)`, you place a capturing group on the start of string anchor that matches an empty string that does not participate in the match due to `?`, thus, `(?(1)...)` statement is looking for `else` part - which is missing (= empty string will do). In other words, the conditional statement evaluates to *false* and the search for `a` right after `eat` is never performed. Thus, there is a match. As an [experiment](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5E)eat(%3F(1)a)&i=eat%2C%20drink%2C%20run), you may remove the `?` from the regex: there will be no match, because *without `?`*, the first captured group *does participate in the match* and the conditional evaluates to *true*.

In case you need to enforce the first capture group evaluation to true and still have it as optional, you will need to use atomic group ([like this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3E(%5E)%3F)eat(%3F(1)a)&i=eat%2C%20drink%2C%20run)) `(?>(^)?)` that will force .NET regex engine to consider the first capturing group as a *valid non-empty captured group*.

Comment: `The optional ? makes the capturing group not to take part in the match` - But realize, even  `(^)?` as optional, will force capture group 1 to be in the matched state (though empty) at BOS, making the conditional true.

Comment: And `thus, (?(1)... statement is looking for else part - which is missing (= empty string will do). Thus, there is a match` - Is not actually true. Either _yes_ or _no_ portions of conditionals can be _empty_. without affecting the result as a whole. Thus `(?(..) )` is valid as well as `(?(..)|)`. In either case, if no expression is provided, it is ignored and has no effect at the occurance of the conditional.

Comment: @sln: Yes, `(^)?` matches an empty string thus failing the conditional check since the name is not a *non-empty captured group*. Sure the *yes* or *no* can be empty strings, here *no* is empty, thus there is a match. Just no search for `a` is performed since the condition evaluates to false.

Comment: `(^)?` actually doesn't match an empty string, it matches the BOS, or nothing. I doesn't matter what the contents of a matched group is (empty or non-empty) as long as it matched. `(\b)?` is the same thing, the group is either matched or not. That's all conditionals care about. This allows a multitude of programming-like flags to be used in expressions.

Comment: @sln: [Check this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5e)%3feat(%3f(1)a)&i=eat%2c+drink%2c+run), the first captured group is actually **empty string**. AND conditional also "care about" [*if expression is matched or name is a valid, non-empty captured group*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e347654k(v=vs.110).aspx). Actually, the `?` is important here. This `?` fails the conditional check. Try removing it from the regex, and you will get no match with the 2nd regex.

Comment: Yep, looks like it optionally doesn't match `^` so it can consume `eat`. But if its forced to `(^)?+eat(?(1)a)` it won't. Your tester doesn't like the nested quantifiers though. Forcing it to match is still optional, but possessive. Maybe your OP can live with `(?>(^)?)eat(?(1)a)` since he's using Dot-Net.

Comment: Proper forced `(?>(^)?)eat(?(1)a)` option using atomic [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3e(%5e)%3f)eat(%3f(1)a)&i=eat%2c+drink%2c+run).

Comment: @sln: Why bother using atomic group? I already mentioned that removing `?` already forces .NET regex engine to evaluate conditional statement to true, and then there is no match. .NET does not support possessive quantifiers, but atomic groups are supported, true.

Comment: You are most welcome. Just in case you ever have to use optional capture groups in JavaScript, you will see a different picture: failed captures *will* paticipate in the match :) But that is a different story.

Comment: please @stribizhev I have a very related question, please check it out, hope you can give me a hand with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257590/regex-are-and-mean-the-same-space ThanksAdvanced.

Answer (score 0):

For Dot-Net style use `(?>(^)?)eat(?(1)a)` or
for Perl style use `(?>(^)?)eat(?(1)a)` or `(^)?+eat(?(1)a)`

This forces the engine to match the BOS (if that's the case)
even when its optional.

If not used possessively, the engine will chose *not* to match `(^)?`
if it has to when trying to satisfy the conditional `(?(1)a)` if not
possible any other way.

Comment: Using atomic group overcomplicates the regex. Removing `?` from `(^)?eat(?(1)a)` is more than enough. And .NET does not support possessive quantifiers (`?+`).

Comment: I know it doesn't support possessive quantifiers. And, removing `?` from `(^)?eat(?(1)a)` forces it to match the BOS at all times, or fail, right at the beginning. Atomic groups, overcomplicated ? How's that exactly ? Kind of absurd..

Comment: @stribizhev - I guess what he's not telling you is 20 minutes before  this post, he asked the real question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252578/if-match-is-in-the-beginning-of-the-string-then-in-regex-conditional) in which he needed a a before and after real consume matches based on a conditional. The part I provided then didn't have the atomic group, which don't work (in that post) without it. So,  he took the part that didn't work (without that) and made another specific question here about it, but with hidden details. That is annoying sometimes. A loss..