# Regex, are "[ ]" and "( )" mean the same (space)?

Tags: regex, string

I have one a question regarding regex

This is my string...

```
cook, eat, write, play
```

In a lot of regex I made before I always refer to space by using `( )` I know I should avoid using `\s` to refer to space, because it includes carriage return, line feed, etc, But why you refer to space using `[ ]` in this regex below?

```
(^)?(?:,[ ])?write(?(1),[ ])
```

I have try to replace the `[ ]` with `( )` in it, like this...

```
(^)?(?:,( ))?write(?(1),( ))
```

But if I do so, the regex doesn't work anymore, why is that?

Why you can refer to space using `( )` in some regex, and why you can not do it in this regex example above?

Comment: Try the expressions on one of the regex sites. They give an explanation of everything in the expression. https://regex101.com/ `[]` is a character class. `()` is a capture group. Character class allows characters inside; capture groups captures the values inside.

Comment: Why do you think the second regex does not work? They both work [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5e)%3f(%3f%3a%2c%5b+%5d)%3fwrite(%3f(1)%2c%5b+%5d)&i=cook%2c+eat%2c+write%2c+play) and [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5e)%3f(%3f%3a%2c(+))%3fwrite(%3f(1)%2c(+))&i=cook%2c+eat%2c+write%2c+play).

Comment: If you have the _ignore whitespace_ flag on, the space between `( )` is ignored, whereas in any mode, the space in here `[ ]` is never ignored.

Comment: Thanks to all, @sln how do you active _ignore whitspace flag_ ?? I have look in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx, I use to enable multine by doing `(?m)` , and single line by doing `(?s)`, but how do you enable ignorewhitspace??? typing this `(?x)`??? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Its just _IgnorePatternWhitespace_. Then you can use formatted, multi-line expressions right in the code (like on my post). Makes for easy reading/maintaining. I'm pretty sure you can use the inline `(?x)` modifier, but it should be the first construct after the `"` code string delimiter. If you use the ignore whitespace, remember that any natural whitespace must be either escaped or within a class (i.e.`[ ]` or `\ `). I recommend using [regexformat](http://www.regexformat.com) to format and compress regexes as it takes care of this automatically.

Comment: For more of something to wrap your head around, the `x` modifier not only ignores whitespace, but it can be turned on/off `(?x) or (?-x)` an where in the code, and is _scoped_ like any local variable if used from the `(?modifiers-modifiers: ...)` construct. This presents interesting, advanced usage possibilities. To play around with it, use _regexformat_, which does formatting with scoping and the expand/un-expand option.

Comment: Thanks @sln you are kinda advanced. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

`()` by default delineates a capture group. `(?: ...)` is a non-capturing group. By delineating a space as `( )` you are matching on a space *and* capturing that space in a capture group.

`(?(1), [ ])` is a test for if the first capture group `(^)` was matched, and if it is, an additional match is performed for the bit in the group.

You don't need to add () or [] around a space to match on it; the literal  character will work fine too!

Your regex still works, FWIW, but I suspect you're relying on capture group indices elsewhere, which is why it's breaking; you've added more capture groups! You can also avoid this kind of dependence on specific group placement by using named capture group:

```
(?<start>^)?(, )?write(?(<start>), )
```

In this case, I'm naming the initial capture group `<start>`, and then later, we can test if `<start>` was matched by name, rather than by index, so that even if you add or remove capture groups, your test always refers to the same capture.

You could also simplify this quite a bit by just having two variants of the match, to avoid testing captures:

```
/^write, |, write/
```

That is, either the string must match the start of the line and the string "write, ", or it must match ", write". The same sentiment is expressed without having to worry about backreference testing.

Comment: Thanks @Chris heald, I really thanks to all, this question was fully answered by all comments before, and this, I don't know who should claim the answer.